# Django-crontab can't make model query

Tags: django, django-models, cron, django-cron, django-crontab

I have a model inside tools app called **ApiKeys** and tried to update the model in specific time intervels. I used django-crontab for this purpose.

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'tools.cron.reset_api_calls','>>logs.log')
]
```

function -

```
from .models import ApiKeys

def reset_api_calls():
    try:
        keys = ApiKeys.objects.all()
            for key in keys:
                key.api_calls = 0
                key.save()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

model -

```
class ApiKeys(models.Model):
    key_token = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    api_calls = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    las_used_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

But it gives error log - `no such table: tools_apikeys`

*Note: The table does exist in database and accessible through django-shell and views.py as well.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work that way, as you need to setup Django for these command to work

You have 2 options

1. Implement this as a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales)
2. Setup Django manually as the start of your script.

   ```
    import django
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
    django.setup()
   ```

Comment: I tried both methods and unfortunately, the package still can't seem to query my database.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your **DATABASES** settings in main project from:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
  }
}
```

to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

by adding **os.path.join** you can specify directory from which system should take a database, because initially it will look for db.sqlite3 in other pwd.